# Using a delay (w3_setTimeOut) with Visual Control Application

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

Using Smart Mobile Studio 2.2.0.4165  (Beta)

I am not sure if I am doing this right, and It may be that I just don't understand how to use the w3_TimeOut callback properly.

The following code locks up when i click the start button. My start button is stuck in the down position, and the program locks up. When I close the program, I then get an "External Exception". I have to restart SMS to do anything more. What have I done wrong?

```
procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: integer;
begin
 //initialize variable
 fRunning:= true;
 repeat
  //get a random light (1-4) and add to array
  fLights.Add(RandomInt(4)+1);
  //step through lights array and light up each light
  for i:= 0 to fLights.Count-1 do
  begin
   LightUp(fLights[i]);
   //add a delay after each
    w3_setTimeOut( procedure ()
    begin
     //shut down light
      LightDwn(fLights[i]);
    end, 200);
  end; //for
 until not fRunning;
end;


procedure TForm1.StopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 //reset variable
 fRunning:= false;
 //clear all lights in array
 fLights.Clear;
end;
I even tried
w3_callback( procedure ()
    begin
     LightDwn(fLights[i]);
    end, 200);
```

If I do not use the delay, and instead, kinda delay it with a show message, it works exactly as I need it too (of course, I can't use the show messages though )

```
procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: integer;
begin
 //initialize variable
 fRunning:= true;
 repeat
  //get a random light (1-4) and add to array
  fLights.Add(RandomInt(4)+1);
  //step through lights array and light up each light
  for i:= 0 to fLights.Count-1 do
  begin

   LightUp(fLights[i]);
   ShowMessage('Up: ' + intToStr(fLights[i]));

   LightDwn(fLights[i]);
   ShowMessage('Down: ' + intToStr(fLights[i]));

  end; //for
 until not fRunning;
end;
```

A simple test shows me that the the w3_TimeOut is not a blocking routine
e.g.

```
procedure TForm1.W3Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 I: Integer;
begin
 for I:= 1 to 99 do
 begin
  w3_setTimeOut( procedure ()
    begin
     //shut down light
      W3Label1.Caption:= IntToStr(I);
    end, 1000);
 end;
```

The label does not get updated until after the loop has completed

I even tried refreshing the form and the label

```
w3_setTimeOut( procedure ()
    begin
     //shut down light
      W3Label1.Caption:= IntToStr(I);
      W3Label1.Invalidate;
      //self.Invalidate;
    end, 1000);
```

But, I do not think i am even doing that properly

after some searching, I found the TW3EventRepeater in the SmartCL.Time.

However, it seems that it works exactly like both the w3_setTimeOut and w3_callback

How do i do a wait() after some code, then when the wait expires, do some more code. it must be a blocking wait?

thanx

**ANSWER:**

```
 fTimer:= TW3Timer.Create;
 fTimer.Delay:= 1000;
 fTimer.OnTime:= HandleTimer;
 fTimer.Enabled:= True;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded, therefore timers are only triggered when your program is not doing anything. Therefore, your event is never called as your program is waiting indefinitely in the repeat..until loop inside `StartClick`.

You should rewrite your program so that:

- Clicking a button sets a timer.
- Everyhing else is executed inside the timer event.

Comment: Thanks!  I finally figured out how to use the TW3EventRepeater and TW3Timer . I have updated the Question with my solution

Comment: However, i still would be interested in knowing how to use  and when to use the following :  w3_SetTimeOut();, w3_ClearInterval(); w3_SetInterval

Comment: These are for things you want to execute "in just a bit". Like say, a few ms after a proc exits. like this:

Procedure TForm1.Something;
begin
  // Do something
  w3_callback( procedure ()
    begin 
      showmessage("done");
    end, 100);
end;

In the above, the showmessage is executed 100ms after the w3_callback is called. Giving you some air between calls.
Excellent for doing cleanup, or enable/disable stuff.